# Calling Mainactivity inside Viewmodel(updated)

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel

For the MVVM architecture, need to call a `WebSocket` variable in the `ViewModel` class.

And my `WebSocket` service is declared in the `MainActivity`.

So, `MainActivity` needs to be instantiated in the `ViewModel`.

I tried to declare an instance::
'''
(activity as MainActivity) 
'''
inside my ViewModel class, but this throws up an error.

I guess the way I have declared `LiveData` variables is not really the best. All I wanted was to access static data of temperature variables (a list of 6. But `MutableLiveData<List<Int>>` wasn't really working out.

Please also suggest how else can I make my `ViewModel` and WebSocket talk to each other.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**problem :**

you have two big mistakes

1-declare web web Socket in activity or fragment

2-use activity in its view model

**explain concept:**

1-you have to declare separated class to web socket implement (create instance ,listen ,invoke,connect and disconnect) to apply single responsibility principle

2-In MVVM the relation between view and view model is one direction view observe observable inside view model and but view model has no reference to  view unlike MVP relation be 2 direction so you shouldn't declare your main activity in side view model

**Solution:**

1-socket class

```
class SocketService{
    companion object {val instance :SocketService}
    fun connect() 
    fun disconnect()
    fun sendMessage(invokeMethodName:String,data:JsonObject)
    fun subscribe(listenMethodName:String,listner:Listner)
    }
```

2-view model

```
  val receiveMessageResponse = MutableLiveData<String>()
      SocketService.instance!!.subscribe(RECEIVE_MESSAGE, HubEventListener {
                receiveMessageResponse.postValue(it)
            })
```

3-activity

```
viewModel.receiveMessageResponse.observe(this, Observer {
         //use the received message here
        })
```

**Conclustion:**

socketService ------> view model ----------> activity

activity <-------- viewmodel <------------- socketService

Comment: Many thanks for to the point answer mate! I tried implimenting your logic to my websocket function but i got really really stuck. Maybe because I am a toddler in android. Pls Excuse me for being a noob, but can you help me with creating the SocketService class?

Would be great if there is a way i can send you the files in a zip format.

Comment: Updates: I have been trying to implement your suggestions. 
So far, I have written my socketservice.java class. 
But the interface between viewmodel-socketservice is not setting up.